# error message fbcdn.net urls are not allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-share

I'm trying to share a post with this code:

```
// Put together the dialog parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setValue:[Campaign sharedInstance].name forKey:@"name" ];
    [params setValue:@"desription" forKey:@"description"];
    [params setValue:picture.facebookPicture.link forKey:@"link"];
    [params setValue:picture.facebookPicture.source forKey:@"picture"];

    // Show the feed dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil                                             parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            [basicViewController toastMessage:[@"Error sharing on Facebook: " stringByAppendingString:error.localizedDescription]];
        }}];
```

I'm getting an error because the source of the picture is from facebook.
What can i do to add the wanted facebook picture and still using the fbwebdialogs?